# Calling Azure Function from another Azure Function

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I have a time-triggered Azure Function written in Python which gets a list of URLs (list is not static). For every URL I want to trigger an Azure Function and pass the URL to it for further processing.

How can I do this transition from one Azure Function to another? What's the best way to trigger the second function and pass the data to it?

Comment: Refer similar question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46315734/how-to-call-another-function-with-in-an-azure-function
As mentioned in the answers you have three options
1. Send an HTTP request to another function's public URL
2. Put a message into an Azure Queue and let the other Azure Function process it
3. Use Durable Functions
Refer the above post for more details

Comment: Thanks. Is there a best practice or guideline when to chose which option?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try to use Durable Functions for this usecase. You will have better control over the activities sharing data from one another.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/quickstart-python-vscode

Answer (score 0):

> How can I do this transition from one Azure Function to another? What's
> the best way to trigger the second function and pass the data to it?

In your situation, you can foreach the list of the urls, create a new httptrigger function, put the url as the body of the request and process the url in the httptrigger function. You can call the httptrigger function by sending request to the httptrigger url.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this one of 3 ways:

1. Once your Function ends, call the http triggered function that you want with a post request and a body filled with data that you want to send.
2. Write the function output to a blob or cosmosdb or postgresdb and create a blob/cosmos/postgres triggered function that triggers off of that input.
3. Create a durable function and chain a few functions together!

Good luck :)