# Can an Azure Function trigger itself?

Tags: azure, http, python-requests, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to do the following with Azure Functions:

```
url='http://localhost:7071/api/testendpoint'


headers = {
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

response=requests.post(url,headers=headers)
```

i.e. "testendpoint" is another endpoint defined in the same function project. This is what I do: endpoint 1 gets a POST request and then the corresponding function code tries to trigger "testendpoint" with a another POST. If i try to do this locally, the function stops responding and runs into a timeout at some point.

Is it not possible to trigger another endpoint in the same function project? Do I have to split my project into multiple Azure Functions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Azure functions most definitely can call other functions in the same function app. Please provide some code examples as the problem most probaly lies in your code.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possibile.
Please find SO topic regarding this subject

[How to call another function with in an Azure function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46315734/how-to-call-another-function-with-in-an-azure-function)

Comment: I tried this. I guess the azure functions block each other since I am blocking the port with the first request while waiting for the response.

Comment: You have already answered yourself, problem is within your code not the Function App host/runetime itself.