# Can I call an azure function from a different class?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

Say if I had these two functions?

```
public static class HelloWorld
{
    [FunctionName("HelloWorld")]
    public static string Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }

}

public static class HelloWorldCall
{
    [FunctionName("HelloWorldCall")]
    public static string Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
    {
        var caller = HelloWorld.Run(req, log);
        return caller;
    }

}
```

1. If I put one in a separate class, would I be able to call it?
2. Can I put function classes in a file to make them more readable or do they need to be top level?

Comment: A function method is just a method. It reacts like any other method in any other class. Now should you call it? That's a different question

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet comes from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55776042/14973743). As you can see, function chaining is available in Durable functions unless you have some reasons not to use that approach.

1. You could call even if the other function is in another class.
2. Not clear what you mean by top level. Each function can be inside a class and in its own .cs file.

Comment: I think my understanding of function apps is a bit unclear. I think Ive got the understanding of calling a function in another class. It was my knowledge of DurableClient that was lacking for that. However what I mean by top level function is, can I put all my functions inside a folder called functions to be basic? As azure doesnt seem to be able to find the functions if they are in a folder. Or is my set up just incorrect?

Comment: Do you mean a folder inside your project structure inside VS?