# Azure Function : returning an http response data in C#

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions

I am using a `HttpClientFactory` to perform a REST API call in my Azure Function:

```
try 
{
    var request = await GetSubmissions.GetFromJsonAsync<HelloWorld>("api/blah");
    return request;
}
catch 
{
    var responseError = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
    return responseError;
}
```

I have created a model called `HelloWorld` like this :

```
namespace Orchestrator_Isolated.Models
{
    public class HelloWorld
    {
        public string Hello { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then I am trying to return the output from this API call within the try block. But I cannot seem to get the return correct.

```
return request
```

I get an error that it cannot convert type (CS0029).

How can I return the request?

This is my full function:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Text.Json;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Azure.Core;
using System.Net.Http.Json;
using Orchestrator_Isolated.Models;

namespace Orchestrator_Isolated
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;
        private readonly HttpClient GetSubmissions;

        public Function1(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
        {
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Function1>();
            GetSubmissions = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("OrchestratorBase"); 
        }

        [Function("HelloWorld")]
        public async Task<HttpResponseData> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get")] HttpRequestData req)
        {
            try 
            {
                var request = await GetSubmissions.GetFromJsonAsync<HelloWorld>("api/blah");
                return request;
            }
            catch 
            {
                var responseError = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
                return responseError;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the whole function or class so we have more to go on?

Comment: Notice how you created a response for the error case. You need to create one for the 200-OK case, too.

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods - absolutley i just wanna see how to return first of all then i can send the 200 too :)

Comment: No, I mean that literally: `var response = req.CreateResponse(statusCode);
        await response.WriteAsJsonAsync(value, statusCode);` and return the `response`.

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods - i see now :) the code i exactly wrote for the error trap  - cheers :) I couldnt see for looking :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call another function with in an Azure function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46315734/how-to-call-another-function-with-in-an-azure-function)